# Create-react-app doesn't hot-reload for yalc updates

Tags: create-react-app

We're trying to add yalc (https://github.com/whitecolor/yalc) to make handling dependencies locally easier. When I publish changes to yalc, they do show up, but only after react is fully shutdown and restarted.

Is there a way to add yalc as one of the things that can reload CRA?

Comment: Any news on this?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use the `--replace` option to force replacement of package content

```
yalc push --replace
```